# How to include a css file in jade (without linking it)

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this jade file:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title test include
    style(type='text/css')
      //- DOES NOT WORK!
      include test.css
  body
    //- works
    include test.css
    div 
      //- works
      include test.css
```

The output:

```
$ jade -P test.jade 
rendered test.html
$ cat test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test include</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      //- DOES NOT WORK!
      include test.css
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>body { color: peachpuff; }

    <div> body { color: peachpuff; }

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, I could simply link the css-file, but I do not want to.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but why not the simple solution?

Comment: I guess that you want to separate CSS from HTML in server files but provide style within html to avoid additional request to get the CSS. 

That is wrong : you add additional computing (file inclusion) for a file that would not be requested every time because it would be cached.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't test it yet (not on my dev computer ATM) but there is a chance doing something like this could work :

```
!!!
head
  title test include
  | <style type='text/css'>
  include test.css
  | </style>
```

By the way, I found the HTML2Jade online converter but not the Jade2HTML. Any idea where to find it ?

Comment: thank you, works! i do not know any online converter. but i found the reason for failing first: "Tags that accept only text such as script and style do not need the leading | character" (https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

Answer (score 9):

From [jade docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/):

```
doctype html
html
  head
    style
      include style.css
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super lame site.
```

It works perfect.

Comment: While this do works,  I want to add that it's equal to the code in the original question, the difference is version(3 years elapsed).

Answer (score 2):

Pass `fs` in as data and you can

```
style !{fs.readFileSync("index.css").toString()}
```

Comment: not exactly cross-implementation safe, but a good hack nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

Arnaud’s answer worked for me, but I’ve since found this is a little cleaner:

```
doctype
head
  title test include
  style(type="text/css"): include test.css
```

The `(type="text/css")` is optional, too, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

In current version of Jade (0.35.0) **it would be enough to write just** `include style.css`.

Complete example (considering you are writing index.jade, which is located in `views` folder, whereas your styles are in `assets` folder):

```
!!!
html
   head
       include ../assets/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap-theme.css
       include ../assets/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css
body
   h1 Hi!
```

**Please note absence of `style` tag** in the template, it would inserted automatically by jade (what a nice feature!).

Comment: As of 1.0.0 (at least), this appears to no longer be the case: if you don't specify some more details the css is just included verbatim, not in a style tag

Comment: you must include a style tag, it will not be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
style(type="text/css").
  #{css}
```

try this with `pug.render(..., { css: yourCssString })`

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be:

```
style(type="text/css")
    #{css}
```

And then pass the css-text in the `res.render(...)` call.

Comment: It is.. it's just a solution for his problem, which i don't really get at all. ;)

Comment: See my comment about his goal ;)