# Jade - Using Block inside script tag

Tags: templates, block, pug

Hi there I'm trying using Jade's **blocks** and **extends** for a node.js project, and the ideia is to have something like this:

layout.jade:

```
head
    script
        $(document).ready(function() {
        block js_doc_ready
            //here goes the doc ready
        });
```

index.jade:

```
block js_doc_ready
    alert('hello!');
    alert('one more js line code');
    alert('end my js doc ready for this view');
```

This would give me a index.html like this:

```
...
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('hello!');
                alert('one more js line code');
                alert('end my js doc ready for this view');         
            });
    </script>
</head>
...
```

But when I see the result, the **'block js_doc_ready'** is not considered a Jade block.
Also, even if it was considered a block, the **"alert('hello!);'** wouldn't be considered a, but a Jade tag.

This is something that I used to do in django template, but in jade with all this tags, and no liberty to do pure html I still find it a little too strange to make this things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Jade do not translate what's inside 'style' and 'script' code. Never.

What will work is based on an answer I gave [to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600487/1265207) (using a style element but that's basically the same).

```
!!!
head
  title Hello jade
  | <script type='text/javascript'>
  | $(document).ready(function() {
      block js_doc_ready
  | });
  | </script>
```

This way : jade will include the HTML 'script' tags and $.ready lines but will also include your block.

Comment: thanks!I archived something like using:

    title Hello jade
    !="<script type='text\javascript'>"
    !="...."
    !=</script>
But this seems a little better... can I have a string with more then on line without using that | ?

Comment: please note: javascript type is 'text/javascript' an not 'text\javascript'

Comment: I think you also forgot to close the ready function.. should be | }); on line 7