# Reference vendor folder css and js in linemanjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, linemanjs

I am creating a web app using `linemanjs` but when I am referencing vendor `css` and `js` files explicitly it wont reference to that location. Let me know what I am doing wrong with linemanjs.

Simple things that I tried in my files is -

`link(rel="stylesheet",href="/vendor/css/myvendor.css")`

**AND**

`link(rel="stylesheet",href="/css/myvendor.css")`

**AND**

`link(rel="stylesheet",href="css/myvendor.css")`

-> `myvendor.css` is surely residing in the css folder under vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not use this elementary tag of basic HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myvendor.css">
```

The path that have to include the tag if must be of the server or client.

If the folder **vendor** contain all file html and folder that contain file that you using for site, the path that I include in the tag before is correct.

If still not include this file **css** , the problem is the file not exist or declared wrong file name or structure css's wrong (Is better that you publish file css) but I think that you find the problem with **Inspect Element** or **Firebug** (add-on for firefox and [perhaps] Chrome)

UPDATE: Ahhh if you using Jade ,adds `'type='text/css'` inside the you tag because is better that you define the type of file.

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/myvendor.css', type='text/css' )
```

Reading the [documentation of JADE](http://johnnyfee.github.io/2014/03/30/jade/) and on

```
Template inheritance

If you have multiple views with a similar structure, you will end up with the same set of includes in all your views. This approach can quickly become complicated and untidy, if the number of views and includes increases.
```

With Jade you can generate the tag including file css with:

```
!!! 5
html
    head
        title Learning Inheritance
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/myvendor.css')
    body
!!!
```

Or there is a other solution posted in other [question on StavkoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595593/how-to-include-a-css-file-in-jade-without-linking-it)

```
head
  title test include
  | <style type='text/css'>
  include css/myvendor.css
  | </style>
```

Comment: I am using `Jade` that is why the link elem is like `link(rel="stylesheet",href="css/myvendor.css")`

Comment: I tried but adding `'type='text/css'` wont fixed the error though :(

Comment: PushState: '/css/myvendor.css' not found in /home/trialcode/trialcode/myapp/generated - Serving up 'generated/index.html'

Comment: It will add and compress into app.css if I declare it in cofig.js file but I need to refer them seperately