# How to make jade loading the css file? (It doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, pug

Here is my directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msDhQ.png)

newTab.jade code

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title New Tab
        link(rel = 'stylesheet', type = 'text/css', href = '/public/index.css')
    body
        p hello world
```

index.css code

```
p{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.locals.pretty = true;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server Connected port: "+port);
});

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('newTab');
});
```

jade file can't loading css file.
I tried
href = "/public/index.css"
but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Check the network tab. Can you observe a request to the CSS file or no?

Comment: I didn't understand meaning "network tab"

Comment: Code I upload is everthing I coded.

Comment: In the developer tools of your browser (F12), there is a network tab that logs the requests a page makes. Open that tab then refresh the page and see what kind of requests that your page makes.

Comment: 2localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: That error usually means the css file can not be found.  Your express configuration doesn't include any static file configuration. Refer [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append a middleware to Express to serve static files too.

In your app.js file:

```
// require path module to join your public folder with __dirname
const path = require('path');

//...

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('newTab');
});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

There are more things `express.static`can do. E.g. setting the `maxAge` for caching purpose:

```
// 31557600000ms = 1 year
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
```

Comment: This is the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

## suggestion

try

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title New Tab
         include index.css
    body
        p hello world
```

on your newTab.jade file

and include index.css on views directory

Comment: `app.set('views', './views');` on app.js file means include views file are on views directory

Comment: discard `link(rel = 'stylesheet', type = 'text/css', href = '/public/index.css')` on newTab.jade file

Comment: "include" tag just loading "text" // p{backgroud.... } is returned at page

Comment: @SeungUnOh indent for few spaces

Comment: @SeungUnOh there should be a space below title

Comment: title has modified lik "New Tabp{background..." I think it doesn't work

Comment: @SeungUnOh jade has a concept with indentation. jade syntax rules [here](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/)

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595593/how-to-include-a-css-file-in-jade-without-linking-it

Comment: thanks for answering, but I used 'link' tag and app.use(~~). and It works. 'include' didn't working for my case. i don't know

Comment: This will output the contents of the css file within the `head` of the HTML document without being wrapped in a `style` tag. The browser won't know what to do with it.